# Yellow versus orange

Tags: differences, adjectives, history, colors

I have observed several people over the years refer to something that is orange in color as "yellow". Is that some linguistic difference or a difference in perception?

Comment: A close friend of mine does not recognize orange as a distinct color, and will refer to anything I'd call orange as either red or yellow.  (I haven't figured out if this is a difference in how he sees things or some quirk in how he learned the words when he was young.)

Comment: @Henry: Perhaps he has a variety of color-blindness.

Comment: I fume every time I see one of these thoroughly mislabelled trucks, even though the name was established long before the colour (swamp holly orange) was decided in a legibility study: http://www.productionmachining.com/cdn/cms/YellowTruck.jpg

Comment: I have seen orange referred as a red in Requiem for a dream movie!   :)

Comment: There's quite a good article on this subject here... http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/colour.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Orange is one of the newest colors, in that in most languages, it was still considered merely a shade of a different color (red or yellow) up until recently[1]. My favorite example of this is the pigment red lead, which isn't red at all, but bright, almost-neon "construction orange". And of course the hair color of most redheads isn't red either.

I don't have any similar examples for orange=yellow, at least not in English[2], but I could totally conceive of someone describing, say, a leaf as yellow, even if technically its color fell closer to the orange spectrum than to strict yellow.

[1] In English, early 16th century. The color was named for the fruit.
[2] The Hungarian word for a carrot is "sárgarépa" = yellow beet.

Comment: Interestingly, also in this vein, is that the Japanese commonly use a single word, *aoi*　(青い) to cover both blue and green. There does exist a separate word for green, "midori" (緑), but the boundaries between what is blue or green are not the same as they are for Westerners.

Comment: also interesting that in russian, light blue, "goluboi", is considered a distinct color. if you show a russian a dark blue and a light blue patch, they will call one blue and the other light blue, saying they are different colors

Comment: I don't know if the Hungarian word for *carrot* counts as an example of an orange thing being called yellow. Carrots weren't necessarily orange until the Dutch started breeding them that way for patriotic reasons in the 17th century: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot#Cultivars

Comment: I wonder if that's why people with orange hair are called 'red-heads'? That is very interesting Martha. Thanks! If the color was named after the fruit, was the fruit named after the House of Orange, like 'William of Orange'?

Comment: BTW, there are many 'new' colors today in English. I still have no idea what color 'taupe' is.

Comment: @bev: Taupe is what designers or decorators call a muted gray-brown. People frequently mix it up with beige and fawn, but these don't have the gray overtones. I suspect you were kidding a little, but decided to give you a straight answer anyway. :)

Comment: @Robusto - I was kidding in a sense, but not in the sense that I knew what 'taupe' is. I do now, thanks to you :-).

Comment: For the `taupe` color, I can give a hit as 'taupe' is the French word for an animal: the `mole`. The name of the `taupe` color is very meaningful in French! It's funny that the color name went untranslated in English.

Comment: @bev, I don't think *taupe* is considered a separate color - it's just a shade of brown or gray. English has lots of color words (crimson, scarlet, maroon, turquoise, lavender, ...) that signify *shades* rather than separate colors. As the language evolves, some of them may start to be considered to be colors in their own right, but I think for that to happen, first there needs to be consensus about precisely what color each term signifies.

Comment: There are tons of fascinating research in that area, Martha. To name but a few most recent experiments, see e.g. the [xkcd color survey results](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/), the results of this [Mechanical Turk experiment](http://blog.crowdflower.com/2008/03/where-does-blue-end-and-red-begin/), or this ongoing [multilingual color-naming experiment](http://colornaming.net/) in which you can actually participate right now.

Comment: @bev: "...was the fruit named after the House of Orange...?" - nope; the root is Sanskrit (*nāraṅga*), suitably corrupted for English use ("a norange" became "an orange").

Comment: In at least one dialect of Chinese, a carrot is referred to as a red turnip （红蘿蔔）

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be a difference in perception. My wife is mildly color-blind, and we sometimes describe the same item with different color words because we perceive it differently.