# Etymology of the color name "orange"

Tags: etymology, nouns, adjectives, colors

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orange) shows

> **orange**
>
> c.1300, from O.Fr. orenge (12c.), from M.L. pomum de orenge, from It. arancia, originally narancia (Venetian naranza), alteration of Arabic naranj, from Pers. narang, from Skt. naranga-s "orange tree," of uncertain origin. Loss of initial n- probably due to confusion with definite article (e.g. une narange, una narancia), but perhaps influenced by Fr. or "gold."
> ...
> Not used as the name of a color until **1540s**.

I am really interested in more details on *why* 'orange' (fruit) was chosen to represent the color. Also, if there are sources that systematically deal with names of colors in different languages or changes over time that would be very interesting, too. Colors are an example of a very stable (static) concept with corresponding terms ('main' colors) for which throughout history there had been a need (more or less important) to have words for.

Bonus question is — what was *orange* called before 1540s in English?

Comment: I think "orange" was just "yellow" before 1540.  I used to study color vision and I remember one study about how to determine standard color sets in different cultures. I think it mentioned the introduction of "orange" into the English language by way of the fruit.  I'll see if I can find it for you.

Comment: @Kit, much obliged, that would be very intersting

Comment: Related: [Yellow versus orange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/yellow-versus-orange).

Comment: I can't remember the exact article, but [this](http://www.essex.ac.uk/psychology/department/people/Roberson_files/bookChapter.pdf) is a summary of cognitive versus linguistic concepts for color that has some really interesting information.  I think the article I'm thinking of is one of the referenced ones, but I don't have my old library on this computer.

Comment: @Unreason: I'm not necessarily convinced *colors are an example of a very stable concept*. The visible spectrum itself is arbitrarily divided by *our* culture into seven colours. Some languages don't even distinguish green from blue, let along orange from red/yellow. English speakers rarely use *cyan* to help subdivide shades of blue. And Homer often said the sea was *wine-coloured*. I think it's all a bit vague.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you have a point, maybe concept is not the right word; I wanted to say that for example blue had always had a wavelength of 440–490 nm and the way we physically perceive it did not change since invention of language (disregarding color blindness as probably not significant for etymology). It is also an immediately available physical attribute. As for not distinguishing; Japanese do, it's just that they have a word for both, similarly how Russians would perceive English word blue - as they have dark and light blue as separate. On the note of blue, Homer used *wine-dark* sea.

Comment: @Unreason: It's often (and credibly, in my view) suggested that the ancient Greeks really didn't perceive much difference between green and blue. They certainly had no word for the latter. Which is still the case in a *lot* of languages today, though there are plenty of others that even distinguish light/dark blue as 'main' colours.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, and I suspect that if we had more detailed etymologies (or from text that explains etymologies in detail) we would understand better why is that.

Comment: @Unreason: I think you'd have to look further than just etymologies. Beyond even language itself, since the whole issue is all interwoven with cognitive psychology, philosophy, and other rarified disciplines.

Comment: @FumbleFingers @Unreason Take a gander at the article I linked to. Divisions in the color spectrum are not arbitrary; they fit a stable pattern, though the number and location of divisions may vary from culture to culture.  That is, while some may not distinguish between blue and green, there are none that have a single word that means both red and blue (without including the wavelengths in between).

Comment: @Kit: I'm sure I read years ago of a language that only had black, white and red. And in evolutionary terms it's quite possible homo sap's ability to distinguish colours has significantly improved *since* we developed reasonable language capabilities.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sure you did read that. I'm sure that study is referenced in the article I linked to, and I'm also sure that the terms for "black", "white", and "red" covered the entire spectrum, not just what *we* conceive of as those colors.

Comment: You can't think of colors as static concepts. For example, Italian doesn't have a word for blue. Or more precisely, it has two words for blue: *blu* and *azzurro,* but neither one encompasses all the shades we call blue.

Comment: @Peter Shor Yes, you *can* think of colors as static concepts.  Just because Italians divide the spectrum differently doesn't mean that colors are not static.

Comment: Well I started off by querying @Unreason's description of colours as 'stable concepts', though I'm guessing [s]he now at least agrees that certainly doesn't mean they're 'univeral constants' with any particular objective existence. But I think research has proved that speakers of languages with two 'main' words for light/dark blue, for example, are better at distinguishing/remembering those shades than speakers with only one word (or none at all, I suppose). We may not *only* think in words, but they certainly colour our thinking, so to speak.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, @Unreason, there's an interesting discussion of colour words at [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/colour.htm).

Comment: @Brian Hooper: Very interesting. Of course the meanings of lots of other words meander over the centuries and millenia, but it does seem colours *as a group* do that quite a bit. Summat to do with being *qualia*, I expect.

Comment: ...mind you, once you've named your colour after a *fruit*, you're pretty much a hostage to botanical variability. Everyone knows what colour *flame-haired* is, even though we increasingly see far more yellow and blue flames, not red ones. Will *orange* be the 'new black' when the growers manage to do with this fruit what they've always tried to do with tulips?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To support the explanation offered by Philoto invoking the intuitiveness of deriving the colour name from the fruit name one can only notice that the phenomenon is a widespread one, observed in many languages and suffering only a few notable albeit easily understandable exceptions.

Here is a whirlwind tour of the various family of names for the fruit and its distinctive colour.

1. The first family is the Anglo French *Orange* and all its cognates

   - Italian **arancia** (fruit) => **arancione** (colour).
   - Spanish **naranja** (fruit) => **naranja** (colour).
   - Portuguese **laranja** (fruit) => **[cor de] laranja** (colour).
2. In Europe, the *sweet* orange was first grown in Portugal in the 15th century <sup>**1**</sup> so that the fruit has a different name all around the mediteranean:

   - Greek **πορτοκάλι** "portocâli" (fruit) => **πορτοκαλί** (colour).
   - Rumanian **portocală** (fruit) => **portocaliu** (colour).
   - Arabic the common word (for the sweet Orange is)  برتقال, **burtuqāl** (the persian  نارنج, nāranğ is only used for the bitter varety).  The colour name is identical **burtuqāl**.
   - Napolitan: **purtuall**<sup>**2**</sup>. AFAIR the colour name is identical.
   - Turkish: **portakal** but the colour is **turuncu** [from Persian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C) **nârenji** (نارنجی) => The bitter variety.
   - Persian: **porteqâl** (پرتقال) (meaning [both sweet orange and Portugal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84)) and **nârenji** (نارنجی) meaning both the colour and the bitter variety.
3. In chinese, the colour (**橙色 *chéngsè***) is named after the fruit (**橙 *chéng***, or **橙子 *chéngzi***) as well.

**Exceptions**

1. One notable exception is the common case of many northern countries in which the fruit has two concurrent names. an older one taken from *Old Dutch* **appelsien** <sup>**3**</sup>  now sinaasappel and a newer one taken from English *orange*.  In which case the colour itself is most of the time a cognate of *orange*.

   - German: **Apfelsine** (old) but still present in *Apfelsinensaft* ‘orange juice’. Now **Orange** (with Orangensaft). colour: **orange**
   - Danish/Norwegian: **appelsin** for the fruit, **orange/oransje** for the colour
   - Icelandic: **Appelsína**, colour **appelsínugulur** (orange-yellow).
   - more to the east: Russian and even Mongolian : **апелсин** . colour: **oранжевый**.
2. In Dominican Republic, the orange colour is actually called "[mamey](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamey)" after the local fruit named [Mammee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammee_apple).  One has to mention though that they *do* have oranges over there but these are actually green.  The Mammey instead is... orange.  QED.

---

**Note 1**
<sup>[German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28Frucht%29)

Während die Bitterorange spätestens im 11. Jahrhundert nach Italien gekommen ist, wurde die süße Variante erst im 15. Jahrhundert nach Europa eingeführt, wo sie zunächst fast ausschließlich in Portugal angebaut wurde.</sup>
<sup>**Translation:** Although the bitter variety was already known inItaly in the 1th Century, the sweet variety was not introduced into Europe until the 15th Century, where it was grown almost exclusively in Portugal.</sup>

**Note 2**
<sup>Napolitan people will tell you that it comes from French "Pour toi" but that's folk etymology</sup>

**Note 3**
<sup>appelsien = Chinese Apple. There is no relation with the original sin although many German contemporary oil paintings depict Adam and Eve together with the snake coiled inside an orange tree.</sup>

Comment: Re the Icelandic example , the colour is [appelsínugulur](http://digicoll.library.wisc.edu/cgi-bin/IcelOnline/IcelOnline.TEId-idx?type=simple&size=First+100&rgn=lemma&q1=appels%EDnugulur&submit=Search) (orange-yellow).

Comment: This is really terrific, Alain. My hat's off to you for this effort. Fascinating stuff.  I wonder what's so compelling about the orange?

Comment: Thanks @Kit. Glad you liked it.  Its colour is quite distinctive and it has a lovely taste. It is actually the most grown fruit on Earth.  It must be popular then.

Comment: +1 Interesting stuff. I remember looking it up after learning in Finnish: the colour is oranssi, the fruit is appelsiini. Both are loanwords, probably from Swedish. Apple, by the way, is omena.

Comment: The fruit is 橙 or 橙子 _chéngzi_ in Chinese; 色 means ‘colour’ and is only part of the name of the colour, not the fruit. Incidentally, it's very common to call oranges 橘子 _júzi_, which is really more specifically a tangerine or mandarin (in itself a reverse etymology, as it were, the fruit being named after the orange robes worn by Chinese mandarins/officials).

Answer (score 7):

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_%28colour%29#Etymology) states this:

> The colour is named after the orange fruit, after the appearance of the ripe fruit. Before this word was introduced to the English-speaking world, the colour was referred to as ġeolurēad (yellow-red).

Why *orange*? I'd speculate, that saying *yellow-red* was a bit awkward (was it a mixed colour or, say, half-yellow and half-red?) and oranges happened to be the most natural source of this colour. At least I cannot think of any other. Except for sun, but it's not always orange.

Comment: There is another natural source: pumpkin.

Comment: @Otavio Macedo Oops, right. They seem to be late for namegiving though :)

Comment: @Otavio And pumpkins are less exotic than oranges. Or maybe because oranges are more exotic than pumpkins?

Comment: @Kit I think in the 16-th century they were evenly exotic (or pumpkins could've been nonexistent there yet, after all they were imported from America)

Comment: @Philoto Ah, yes, of course.  But pumpkins grow more easily in the English speaking parts of Europe, I'd imagine, so I could have grown my own, but I would have had to buy oranges.  What do you think? Maybe?

Comment: @Kit We can try to start saying *the sun is pumpkin at sunset*. Together?

Comment: Pumpkins aren't native to Europe they arrived long after oranges and still aren't very common

Comment: @Kit: off-topic..but what do Native Americans call the pumpkin and what do they call the color?

Comment: @Martin Beckett Pumpkins aren't common in Europe? Weird. They are about the easiest things to grow.  But there you have it, I suppose: oranges came first. @Mitch I have no idea.

Comment: @kit - easy to grow but disgusting to eat! Apparently the `carve out for halloween` variety are now more common in Europe because of the influence of US TV shows but nobody eats the stuff.

Comment: @Mitch: The word _pumpkin_ is European in origin. _Squash_, on the other hand, comes from the Narragansett word _askutasquash_, meaning "eaten
raw or uncooked." Also, pumpkins come in many [colors](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=705&site=images&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=multicolored+pumpkins&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) and I think the bright orange one may be newer. Its predominance definitely is (unfortunate since other varieties are better eating).

Comment: @Callithumpian: the pumpkin varieties I've seen that are grown to be eaten are also orange, but much tastier than the variety grown to be carved.

Comment: I don't think *ġeolurēad* is awkward at all.  Unlike *orange*, which sounds like a foreign word.

Comment: Why is *yellow-red* any more awkward than *blue-green*?

Comment: Pumpkins vary in their commonness. In England, we never seen them except at Halloween. In fact, supermarkets seem to discard them on 1 November, rather than attempt to sell them as food. By contrast, I remember visiting colleagues in Graz some years ago, and being told by them that the traditional Styrian crop of pumpkin was being debased by cheap imports of Hungarian pumpkins, which were being processed in Styria, and products sold as "Styrian". This was prompted by me ordering a salad dressed with pumpkin oil.

Comment: At the bottom of all these comments, I mischievously whisper *carrots*.

Comment: @kit I don't have a reference to hand but do recall reading recently that the orange colour of carrots is the result of comparatively recent cultivation. Previously white was the predominant colour alongside variously coloured varieties.

Comment: @Kit, I miscievously mumble that carrots come in all sorts of colours, but the Dutch cultivated orange ones from purple carrots in the 17th century to support Dutch independence and -- what else? -- the House of Orange. :)

Comment: @Hugo: Wow! That is just brilliant! I had no idea. Long live the Queen! *throws carrots at the Golden Carriage*

Answer (score 2):

Before the 1540s, orange was just a shade of yellow. Colour is a continous spectrum, so who says there's seven colours in the rainbow? There's six, or twenty, or 20,000 or millions of shades depending on how far you break it down.

Just like, how many fractions are there between 0 and 1? Halves? Thirds? Quarters?

Comment: wiki: "A rainbow spans a continuous spectrum of colours—there are no 'bands.' The apparent discreteness is an artefact of the photopigments in the human eye and of the neural processing of our photoreceptor outputs in the brain. Because the peak response of human colour receptors varies from person to person, different individuals will see slightly different colours, and persons with colour blindness will see a smaller set of colours. However, the seven colours listed below are thought to be representative of how humans everywhere, with normal colour vision, see the rainbow"

Answer (score 1):

In English the colour Orange clearly used to be called Red; hence Robin Red-breast which is actually orange. Other examples are red deer, red head, red kite and red squirrel.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clearly'?  All the robins, deer, kites and squirrels where I live are clearly red, not orange.

Answer (score 0):

Orange was called "orenge".

The color 'orenge'.
ORANGE = the name of a fruit. (F.,- Ital., -Pers.) The pl.orenges is in Sir T. Elyot, Castel of Helth, b. ii. c. 7. ' 
"Colour of orenge"' occurs in 1. 7 of a 15th-century ballad beginning 'O mossie Quince,' pr. in Chaucer's Works, ed. 1561, fol. 344, back; and see Orange in Prompt. Parv. O. F. orenge (14th century), Littre; later changed into orange, ' an orange ; ' Cot. The form should rather have been narenge, but the initial 'n' was lost, and arenge became orenge under the influence of F. 'Or' (Lat.aurum), gold ; because the notion arose that the name denoted the golden colour of the fruit.
Ital. arancio, an orange, an orange-tree. Cf. Span, naranja, Port.laranja (put for naranja), an orange. Pers. ndranj, ndrinj, also narang, an orange ; Rich. Pers. Diet. p. 1548. Cf. Pers. ndr, a pomegranate.
Source:
AN ETYMOLOGICAL DICTIONARY OF THE ENGLISH LANGUAGE.BY REV. WALTER W. SKEAT,

It is recorded in the ballad by Chaucer.

O Mossie Quince........
https://books.google.nl/books?id=bO5LAAAAcAAJ&pg=PR16&lpg=PR16&dq=%27O+mossie+Quince,%27&source=bl&ots=V2CwoJVdbR&sig=f4ASsRqsQzW-Q7o9cC1O9dDIi78&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwgKif94HdAhXC26QKHTO8D1kQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q='O%20mossie%20Quince%2C'&f=false

Comment: You should really fix the formatting in this answer. However, I don't see "colour of orenge" as convincing evidence that orange was a color at that point in time. It seems to be similar to saying that, for example, someone has "hair the color of dirt" but it wouldn't make sense to say that someone has "dirt hair" because "dirt" isn't a color (hopefully this makes sense).